# How to configure Wildfly to connect to remote Artemis server?

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis, thorntail

I cannot configure Wildfly 14.0.1.Final to connect to the remote Artemis server. Here is my standalone.xml:

```
      <server name="default">
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <remote-connector name="remote-artemis" socket-binding="remote-artemis"/>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
            </in-vm-connector>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
            </in-vm-acceptor>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="remote-artemis" entries="java:/jms/remoteCF" connectors="remote-artemis" user="admin" password="admin"/>
        </server>
```

And here is my MDB:

```
@ResourceAdapter("remote-artemis")
@MessageDriven(name = "ExampleMdb", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "DMSQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") })
    public class ExampleMdb implements MessageListener {}
```

I have DMSQueue in DMSQueue address on Artemis server. 
This is what I get in Wildfly console:  `AMQ151001: Attempting to reconnect org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivationSpec(ra=org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.ActiveMQResourceAdapter@9382da9c destination=queues/DMSQueue destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=admin password=**** maxSession=15)`

 and 
`AMQ151004: Instantiating javax.jms.Queue "DMSQueue" directly since UseJNDI=false.`

What I can see in Artemis web console is that there are two connections and one session from Wildfly and one registered producer, but no consumers. I also tried configuring this with Thorntail but got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the documentation here: https://docs.wildfly.org/14/Admin_Guide.html#Messaging_Connect_a_pooled-connection-factory_to_a_Remote_Artemis_Server

Assuming you have the `remote-artemis` socket binding defined (you don't show that), it seems you have to configure the MDB to use the specific resource adapter by annotating it with `@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter("remote-artemis")`.

If the MDB isn't configured to use a specific resource adapter, either by this annotation or by some other means, the default resource adapter configured in the `ejb3` subsystem will be used.

The rest of your configuration looks good (according to the docs, I'm no expert on messaging :-) ).

Comment: You are right, I was playing around and forgot to write it in a question. But I have it on my mdb, so I edited the question. I still have a problem.

Comment: Which version of Artemis are you using ?